# Best way to choose the best component?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm building an expert system who should be able to assemble a computer after asking some question to the user to understand his needs! My problem is to choose the best processor, the best ram, the best VGA ecc ecc to show to the user just one configuration!
The components are stored like these:

```
configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H, Dvd, Price_range) :-
processor(P, Proc_price, Price_range),
motherboard(M, Motherboard_price, Price_range),
ram(R, Ram_price, Price_range),
case(C, Case_price, Price_range),
ali(A, Ali_price, Price_range),
video_card(V, Vga_price, Price_range),
ssd(S, Ssd_price, Price_range),
monitor(D, Monitor_price, Price_range),
dvd(Dvd, Dvd_price, Price_range),
hdd(H, Hdd_price, Price_range).
Price is Proc_price + Motherboard_price + Ram_price + Case_price + Ali_price + Vga_price + Ssd_price + Dvd_price + Monitor_price + Hdd_price.
```

I'm not asking you to do that for me, I'm just asking some suggestions to do that, I probably have to add some elements for each component and maybe some relations but I'm at an impasse at the moment.

EDIT:

I've defined the configuration predicate but in this way I'm able to define all the possible configurations by using `forall`/`findall`, but I need to generate just the best configuration, so maybe I need to define one choosing predicate for each component.

You talked about a score, I could set a score for each component who means how the component is suited to satisfy the user.

I've added some relationships between components, I should use them while defining the configuration. About these relationships, I'm not sure if I have to to store them like other components by default or I have to assert them, for instance by checking if bot components have the same socket.

```
compatibility(motherboard, processor)
compatibility(motherboard, ram) 
compatibility(motherboard, vga)
compatibility(processor, ram)
```

Comment: "Best" in what sense? I would suggest following the "generate-test" paradigm, where you first make a generator function that produces configurations, and then augment that with a test function that determines if the configuration is sensible. So make a `configuration` predicate that gives you legitimate configurations and some kind of `score` predicate that helps you determine how great a configuration is.

Comment: I helped someone with [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146990/how-can-i-assign-multiple-values-to-a-variable-like-a-string-in-prolog) last fall, in case it helps.

Comment: In addition to the link Daniel provided, you just need to organize your thoughts and information. First, what are the facts? Those should be asserted in your program. I assume they look like the terms you show in your question. You would have many of each of them, and they correspond to different specific makes/models of items with their specific prices, etc. Then, also as Daniel points out, you need to decide what "best" means. What are you measuring as "best"? That's what then has to be translated into a Prolog rule (predicate/s).

Comment: @lurker I've edited the first post, please see it

Comment: @DanielLyons I've edited the first post, please see it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the semantics of `compatibility`. What does it mean when you say `compatibility(A, B)` (that `A` is compatible with `B`)? Or does that really mean "has"?

Comment: A is compatible with B, for instance a motherboard A and a processor B are compatible because of they have the same socket

Comment: It's still unclear how you are defining "best". Daniel suggested a `score` predicate that would evaluate a configuration and provide some relative measure of how "good" configuration is. Then you could pick the "best" by choosing the one with the highest "good" score. For example, is "best" determined by highest performance regardless of cost? If so, then performance needs to be assessable from your facts.

Answer (score 6):

Given that you are described an object made of several components, an interesting approach is to use DCGs to express the composition of components. For example:

```
computer --> monitor, keyboard, mouse, motherboard.

motherboard --> [motherboard], memory, processor.

memory --> [memory].
processor --> [processor].
monitor --> [monitor].
keyboard --> [keyboard].
mouse --> [mouse].
...
```

You can then use the `phrase/2` predicate to get the list of parts required to build something. For example:

```
| ?- phrase(computer, Parts).
Parts = [monitor, keyboard, mouse, motherboard, memory, processor]
yes
```

Of course, you can easily have different alternatives (i.e. build different computers) by adding more grammar rules. E.g. a premium motherboard with a discrete video card vs a basic motherboard with integrated graphics.

After getting the basic whole/parts described, you can start adding characteristics such as price by augmenting the grammar rules. For example:

```
computer(Price) -->
    monitor(MonitorPrice),
    keyboard(KeyboardPrice),
    mouse(MousePrice),
    motherboard(MotherboardPrice),
    Price is MonitorPrice + KeyboardPrice + MousePrice + MotherboardPrice.
```

You may also use constraints for greater flexibility (e.g. easily list assemblies within a price range).

Comment: @PauloMoura I've edited the first post, please see it